gaining research experience in anthropology in US
Where can I get research experience in the social sciences, especially politics or anthropology? I am no longer in my bachelor's degree, making it a lot more difficult to get any experience.
How do I get publications with no mentor and no guidance?
I want to increase my chances for PhDs in the US and I'm reading that many people already have publications. I'm a US resident, but did my BA and MA in the EU.

Sorry I can't say too much about anthropology specifically, but there are basically two ways to get research experience:

Be a student and do research

Get a job to do research


I would strongly recommend against the third "independent research" path. You'll waste your time without guidance, and all the people who can usefully guide you are busy advising their students.
If you've already graduated, it's up to you to evaluate the cost-benefit of (1): education in the US is expensive, is it worth getting an entire degree just to get some research experience to possibly join a PhD program?
The availability of (2) depends on your field, experience and skills, and network. I work in a field where it's common to hire people with just a bachelor's degree for junior research positions, but a lot of those positions are filled by recent students.
My impression of social science in general is that these are usually "low money" fields which might mean that these positions don't exist at all. You might find special roles if you have special skills to bring, though, for example if you are fluent in multiple languages there might be opportunities in translation. You'll just need to look for jobs at universities in your field and see if they exist and if so talk to the person hiring about your goals.

I think the reason you haven't gotten answers here is that it is pretty much impossible to meet the conditions of your two questions.
One doesn't need a mentor to publish, but one normally needs guidance in developing something that is publishable, until they gain the experience to make their own judgments and find their own insights.
And, it is especially difficult if you are moving to a new field. But that is what graduate study is meant to do. I've said elsewhere here that you don't enter a doctoral program to prove that you don't need to do that.
I'd guess that a field like anthropology might be especially difficult to get in to informally. Especially if something like field work is implied. People have enough to do managing their own students. But, the field is pretty broad, of course.
I doubt that all that many people starting doctoral study in the US have a publication record that has a lot of value. But that is because most doctoral study in the US begins with only a bachelors. It is difficult here to get any meaningful research done because of the nature of the program which is very general, with only a portion devoted to the "major" subject. Combine that with the fairly strict time constraints and it becomes hard to do open-ended research that makes a real contribution to knowledge. I remember with some horror my first undergraduate attempts, and not much better at the masters level. But that was no impediment to my beginning doctoral study.
However, if you want to study for a doctorate in the US, the path is to make application to a few programs. You will need good letters of recommendation from people who know you well and can make an honest prediction of your likelihood of success.
Note also, that changing fields when starting a doctorate is relatively common here, but, again, because of the broad nature of the undergrad education.
Since you are a US resident, one way to get an idea is to visit an anthropology department here and ask to speak to one of the professors (during office hours). They can look at your CV and give you a sense about your chances, and possibly a path forward.
